# Find $\oint_C \frac{1}{z^6+1} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find $$\oint_C \frac{1}{z^6+1} dz$$ when

a) $C$ is a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $i$

b) $C$ is a circle of radius 1 cntered at $\left( \frac{1+i}{2} \right)$

Comment: I've been looking at this equation, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{z}{z-z_0} n+1 dz$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the residue theorem together with the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n\ge0}x^n$$
for $\|x\|<1$.